# numpy: unpack array along an axis

Tags: numpy

Say that I have a RGB image:

```
from skimage import data
img = data.astronaut()
print(img.shape)  # (512, 512, 3)
```

Is there a succinct numpy command to unpack it along the color channels:

```
R, G, B = np.unpack(img, 2)  # ?
```

---

What I am doing is using comprehension:

```
R, G, B = (img[:, :, i] for i in range(3))
```

But is there no simpler command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively you can use [`np.rollaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) -

```
R,G,B = np.rollaxis(img,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose the length-3 dimension to the front and then unpack it:

```
R, G, B = img.transpose((2, 0, 1))
```

Comment: I will give some time for anyone else to throw a suggestion, but that is pretty clever. :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `np.split`:

```
R, G, B = np.split(img, img.shape[-1], axis=-1)
```

If your array is of shape (height, width, channel), you can use `np.dsplit` to split along the depth dimension:

```
R, G, B = np.dsplit(img, img.shape[-1])
```